# Processing emails for multiple accounts using POP3

Tags: c#, asp.net

suppose I want to process emails for multiple accounts using a tool like OpenPop.net or any other tool. I.e.

```
Check the server for new emails for a give number of accounts
copy sender,recipient,subject etc into a database.
```

How do I access these emails through code without having the user supply username and password? That is, is there a way that the application can access and use the Mail server user database, access the login credentials for each of the specified users and use them to retrieve their emails?

If not, how else would I go about this? I'm looking at a scenario where I'm able to process emails when they come in even in situations where the user doesn't login.

Comment: I wish people would comment when downvoting. How are people expected to fix their questions and become better members of the community if nobody will tell them what they actually did wrong?

Comment: You want access to other peoples email?

Comment: Actually I thought that there is a way to access all email accounts in a given server without the users supplying the passwords. But after research I've concluded that you have to get the email and password from the user to be able to access the inbox via POP3

Answer (score 0):

If the account has a username and password, and you access it over POP, it will require authentication.

There may be a way to access the email database directly but this would depend on the mail server in question.